# A person who does you a favour then uses it against you?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the word for a person who does you a favour then uses it against you?

Comment: swindler / trickster / con man / con artist / crook , etc.

Comment: In the immortal wisdom of Weird Al Yankovic, such a person would be referred to as "tacky".

Comment: The act is usually called _keeping score_. Not sure if there's a noun that exactly defines such a person--perhaps _scorekeeper_? :-)

Comment: Also, welcome to the EL&U site. Please provide an example of how you would use such a word (in a sample sentence) and include any prior research you may have done. As it stands, your question is in danger of being closed. Please take the [help tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Comment: @Tragicomic I would pop that one (*scorekeeper*) into an answer, if I were you.

Comment: @WS2: Thanks, I wasn't sure this would work, but I have. :-)..

Comment: Whilst this may appear to be duplicitous behaviour, the question doesn't give an example nor context, and consequently we could refer to the behaviour as duplicitous obligation, or indebted duplicity.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by 'using it against you'. If it's simply the clear expectation that the favour should be returned, then the person has 'put you in his debt'.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call that person [***manipulative***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manipulative).

> Exercising unscrupulous control or influence over a person or situation:
>   *she was sly, selfish, and manipulative*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manipulative

Answer (score 2):

The act of doing something for someone and then expecting something in return is usually called [*keeping score*](http://www.oneworldofenglish.com/english_idioms/idioms_K/keep_score.htm). I don't think there's a noun that exactly defines a person who does this--you *might* call them *scorekeeper*.